# Horizontal-only pinch zoom in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipinchgesturerecognizer, contentoffset

I'm using a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to adjust the width (not the height) of a view in a `UIScrollView`. It works with the pinch gesture's `scale` property, but the `contentOffset` of the scrollview doesn't change, so the view always increases on the right. This looks a bit better if I scale the `contentOffset` along with the width, since then the view increases from the left-most side of the screen.

The problem is that the location of the pinch is ignored - so it always appears that a pinch is on the left side of the screen.

I need to somehow factor in the location of the pinch to the `contentOffset` adjustment, so that the offset can be adjusted to keep the content at the pinch point to be in the same place.

Note: I cannot use built-in `UIScrollView` pinch-zoom gesture as I only want the zoom to be one dimension, horizontal. Also, I cannot use transforms on the `UIView` as I need to use the `UIScrollView`.

Comment: The superclass of `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` has a few methods that may help, such as `-locationInView:`. (Are you asking how to locate the pinch? That much isn't clear)

Comment: Yes, pictures would have helped make this question clearer. I ended up using `locationInView:` to determine the pinch point, normalized it (0..1), resized the view, calculated the new pinch point, and then set the offset so the pinch point is under the touch point.

Comment: can you post your solution?

Comment: Pinch handler posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was pinch zooming a graph, so the pinch adjusts the width constraint on the graph view.

Here is the pinch handler:

```
- (void) doPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinch;
{        
    CGFloat width = self.graphWidthConstraint.constant;
    CGFloat idealWidth = 1500;
    CGFloat currentScale = width / idealWidth;
    CGFloat scale = currentScale - (1.0 - pinch.scale);

    CGFloat minScale = 0.5;
    CGFloat maxScale = 3.0;
    scale = MIN(scale, maxScale);
    scale = MAX(scale, minScale);

    CGPoint locationScrollview = [pinch locationInView:self.graphScrollView];
    CGFloat pinchXNormalized = locationScrollview.x / width;

    CGPoint locationView = [pinch locationInView:self.view];

    // resize
    CGFloat newWidth = idealWidth * scale;
    self.graphWidthConstraint.constant = newWidth;

    // set offset to position point under touch
    CGFloat pinchXScaled = newWidth * pinchXNormalized;
    CGFloat x = pinchXScaled - locationView.x;
    self.graphScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x, 0);

    pinch.scale = 1;
}
```